# What am I not seeing? Am I understanding the recv function wrong or is this while loop doing something unexpected?

Tags: c++, while-loop, tcp, recv

To give an idea, my program is communicating via tcp/ip with a simatic sps and for that I am using one socket to send and receive data. The SPS gets the data, dose stuff with it and when it is ready it sends data back. Now if I implemented and understand all this right once the SPS sends the data back this while loop should convert the data and send it to an csv function of mine. The thing is in the first try, when the SPS got the info, it did its stuff and has sent the data, this while loop doesn’t even get to the csv function and therefore never exits the loop. If I start the process while the SPS already is finished and has sent the data it get to the csv function and leaves the loop. I can tell that the recv is not giving out an error because that would show up on the SPS with a dead connection.

Maybe my problem is that I am trying to use only one socket? Can anyone confirm this assumption? I haven’t found any there that I am not supposed to use one socket for both send and receive.

```
// Wait for response    
bool active = true;
do
{
    char buf[4096];
        
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
    int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    if (bytesReceived > 0)
    {
        short int* ibuf = (short int*)buf;
        std::vector<int> InputData;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesReceived / 2; ++i, ++ibuf)
        {
            short result = ntohs(*ibuf);
            InputData.push_back(result);
        }
        if (CsvWriter(InputData) == 0) {
            active = false;
        }
    }

} while (active == true);
```

Comment: If the loop is not exiting, your `recv()` is either hanging, or returning -1, or 0. You should log its return value to be able to tell which one it is, and handle the case accordingly.

Comment: If you have an error, you *still* run your loop. You should exit the loop on error, and preferably also log it.

Comment: And as you seem to know, `recv()` can return `0` which means the connection has been closed from the other side and you should close your side of the connection too. You don't handle this case at all.

Comment: I'd say the lesson for today is to learn how to *debug* your code. If you use common debugging techniques ("printf" debugging where you print all variables and their values, or using an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values) I'm sure you would figure out the problem quite easily.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude that is what I normally do, printing out with printf but in this project I am also doing window / user interface programming so I don't have a console to output and I have struggled for hours to have also a console running to output, I know it is possible I saw it yet somehow I did something wrong, again. Ended up with window pop ups as output. The funny thing is all of my code worked separately after I combined it a lot of problema started.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, I am starting to lose my mind, i just finished adding some pop ups to see what errors might be happening. Funny thing is I now tried everything on my personal setup, and everything works???? Not a Single issue at all?!?!?  Visual Studio 2019 has a debugger right or are there other, maybe better tools for that?

Comment: Visual Studio has a very good debugger. Also note that for Windows it's still possible to open up a console window for "printf" debugging, or you could use files (but remember to flush after each output). I personally recommend using the debugger though. Also build with extra warning enabled (for the MSVC compiler add the `/W4` option), and treat each and every warning you get as an error that must be fixed.

Comment: As a note about things suddenly starting to work when you added some things, it could be a sign that you have *undefined behavior* somewhere in your code. That could actually make it even harder to debug, especially if the problem is because of uninitialized variables as the debugger could initialize them, perhaps to zeroes which for pointers will then be equivalent to null-pointers, so any null-pointer check suddenly works as expected while it doesn't work in your release build.

Comment: Another debugging technique is to remove code until it all starts working as expected again (very easy if you also use a versioning system like Git), or if you don't have too much code written already you could scrap it all and start over. Then add in a ***small*** piece of code, make sure it builds without warnings, and test it to make sure it works. Only then you add the next ***small*** piece of code. And so on. If you get the error back, you could isolate it easily to the last piece of code you added, and can concentrate your debugging on that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude found the problem. On the SPS the receive kept busy even though it already was done, I might have forgotten to add something like this is the complete message or maybe closing the socket? Fixed it by using a second dedicated Socket for sending. I think I am finally understanding how the sockets work or maybe I am just interpreting this in. Must find out with my next Project.

Comment: Sockets are fully duplex, and can be used for both sending and receiving by both ends of a connection. The problem is, as you mentioned, there's no way to know when a message have finished transmission, as TCP is a streaming protocol (it's a stream of bytes without meaning for TCP itself). If you want to send messages you need to invent a protocol on top of TCP which include things to distinguish between messages or when a connection is to end. Early HTTP used the simple way: Just close connection once all data is sent.

Comment: [Continues...] Other ways include having some kind of end-of-message marker, for example the carriage return-newline pair `\r\n`. Or perhaps have a fixed-sized header which includes the length of the data to be sent in each message. And to not pick on the two-socket solution, that's how the old FTP protocol could work, one command-socket that transmits commands, and when sending data a new connection was made.